# True or false? If $\Gamma \cup{p}\vDash q$, then $\Gamma\vDash p\to q$

Tags: logic

I keep going back and forth as to whether this is true or false.

> True or False? Where true, provide a proof. Where false, provide a counterexample i.e., a particular case that demonstrates the claim is false.
>
> $$\text{If}\quad\Gamma \cup\{p\}\vDash q,\quad\text{then}\quad\Gamma\vDash p\to q$$
>
> **Important Note:** All counterexamples should be in our formal language, not in English. Also, $p$ and $q$ are variables. They are not sentences of our formal language, and so, should not appear in any counterexample.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is true. An easy way to see it is this:

1. Assume $\Gamma \cup p \models q$
2. By completeness, $\Gamma \cup p \vdash q$
3. By the deduction theorem, $\Gamma \vdash p \to q$
4. By soundness $\Gamma \models p \to q$

Comment: thank you . yes, I figured it was true by using a tree test, am just having a hard time proving it.  I haven't been introduced to the deduction theorem yet.  thanks - I think reading about that will help.